# Limit in SPARQL results

Tags: api, sparql, limit, graphdb, rdf4j

I run a `SPARQL` query in `graphDB` from an `API REST` and I get only the first 1000 rows back. I am not using a `LIMIT` clause at the end of my query. I found in the documentation that number is a default result set limit but how can it be overridden without download the data? Because that is the solution what graphDB team propose.

Comment: who exactly do you run a SPARQL query via REST? Can you show the REST call please?

Comment: typo: (I meant **"how"**)

Answer (score 1):

Some sparql endpoints have a limit to the data you can fetch with one query. It can change from endpoint to endpoint, generally it is 10,000 triples. You can still use pagination to get more results. In the SPARQL language you should use OFFSET. Here you can find documentation on how to use it: https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#modOffset